# MATLAB vectorize nested for loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Hi I am struggling with matlab vactorization any help on this would be great thanks.

`oldLocation`, `Limit_` are both matrices

```
   for i=1:250
       for j=1:350
           temp= oldLocation(i,j,:)./Limit_(i,j,:);
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just perform the division directly. Of course, you'll need to adapt the code that follows (unless you keep overwriting `temp`)

```
temp = oldLocation./Limit_;
```